# React native app runs on emulator, but errors on device

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, react-native

I created a react-native mobile application. This app runs in emulator with this build.gradle file

```
    buildscript {
        ext {
            buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
            minSdkVersion = 21
            compileSdkVersion = 29
            targetSdkVersion = 29
            ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
        }
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")
            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            mavenLocal()
            maven {
                // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
                url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
            }
            maven {
                // Android JSC is installed from npm
                url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
            }
    
            google()
            jcenter()
            maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
        }
    }
```

But when I want to create an apk file by android studio, I get these errors

```
    Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
    > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath'.
       > Could not find collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0).
         Searched in the following locations:
             https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/collection/collection/1.0.0/collection-1.0.0.jar
       > Could not find lifecycle-runtime-2.0.0.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0).
         Searched in the following locations:
             https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/lifecycle/lifecycle-runtime/2.0.0/lifecycle-runtime-2.0.0.aar
       > Could not find lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0).
         Searched in the following locations:
             https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/lifecycle/lifecycle-common/2.0.0/lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar
       > Could not find core-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0).
         Searched in the following locations:
             https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/arch/core/core-common/2.0.0/core-common-2.0.0.jar
       > Could not find annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0).
         Searched in the following locations:
             https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/annotation/annotation/1.0.0/annotation-1.0.0.jar
    
    Possible solution:
     - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

by changing build.gradle to these codes...

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
    classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        maven {
         url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
        // Android JSC is installed from npm
             url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

I could generate an Apk file, but when I run this app on mobile, nothing happened. After i taped on the app icon once again, this error appears
"sample keeps stopping, send bug report to Mi for analysis..... View summary"
and this is the summary

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes.so
    SoSource 0: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.sample/lib-main flags = 1]
    SoSource 1: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /data/app/com.sample-KGICJtcYx9H_O-Z0nmW6YA==/lib/arm64 flags = 0]
    SoSource 2: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /vendor/lib64 flags = 2]
    SoSource 3: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /system/lib64 flags = 2]
    Native lib dir: /data/app/com.sample-KGICJtcYx9H_O-Z0nmW6YA==/lib/arm64
 result: 0
    at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.doLoadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:896)
    at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoNameImpl(SoLoader.java:725)
    at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:649)
    at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:629)
    at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:577)
    at com.facebook.hermes.reactexecutor.HermesExecutor.<clinit>(HermesExecutor.java:20)
    at com.facebook.hermes.reactexecutor.HermesExecutorFactory.create(HermesExecutorFactory.java:29)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:1024)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Comment: I found the solution 
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25923#issuecomment-626663209